# database design numerical range

Tags: php, mysql

i want to design a database that contain numerical range in it

this database desgined for production year

most of products have a one [year] value for example `2013`

but some of them contain numerical range
eg : `1990 - 2010`

i want to make advanced search by  Production year

for example user can search into products that made between 2010 and 2014

but ,

how i should save production year ( normal or serialized ) ?

or i should have two columns with the name year1 , year2 ?

i don't how to design some thing like this

note : i must design it with the most efficient way , because many users using this search

Comment: two columns start year and end year would be the best approach make sure the data type is date

Comment: @Sam D and in this way how to run sql query ? `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE year1 and year2 BETWEEN 1994 and 2000` it will be wrong for example if i have product that made between 1995 and 1997 it's not work

Comment: The query would be more like: `$startYear = 1994; $endYear = 2000;` `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE year1 <= $endYear and year2 >= $startYear` This captures all possible rows that overlap the year1 and year2 values at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most suitable option is using two columns representing both years (startYear/endYear). 
If you have just one value representing the range you can fill both startYear and endYear using this value (let's say startYear <= 2013  and endYear <= 2013).

Then you can use something like this

```
`SELECT lala FROM lala WHERE startYear <= $num1 AND endyear >= $num2`
```

Comment: Your query is wrong. You need to swap the `$num1` and `$num2` variables. The query should be `...WHERE startYear <= $num2 AND endyear >= $num1` or else you will not match all possible overlaps of time.